# How to remove space above and below text view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, textview, swiftui

I have a text with a size of 80. When I put a border on this view, I see that there is additional space above and below the text. To save space in my application, I need to remove this space. But I don't know if it's possible properly?

Exemple of code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("360°")
      .font(Font.system(size: 80, weight: .thin, design: .default).monospacedDigit())
      .border(Color.red, width: 2)
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: Screen result]

I need the green result:

[image: Screen result I need]

Comment: Hello there, did you try with '.padding(.bottom, 100)' and top you can give negative values too like .padding([.top], -6) or some other value, just try and let me know :)

Comment: No result with padding

Comment: @Guillaume add `.padding(.vertical, -15)` above border. Adjust as per your need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vertical space is occupied by the `Text` itself. Adding fixed negative padding isn't recommended. Use this, only if both text and font are hardcoded.

```
Text("360°")
    .font(Font.system(size: 80, weight: .thin, design: .default).monospacedDigit())
    .padding(.vertical, -18)
    .border(Color.red, width: 1),
```

[image: Output]