# SwiftUI - How to remove gap between text content and text background?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to align text content relative to other Views precisely. To have more control in this alignment, I want to make either the text content fill the text background or make the text background shrink to the text content. Given the code below, what modifications should I add to satisfy the above conditions?

I have tried playing around with padding and spacing, but they do not satisfy my conditions.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello.")
            .font(Font.system(size: 50))
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[This photo demonstrates what I would like to have removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dse0k.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're going for, here, but are you looking for the `frame` view modifier, maybe? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(width:height:alignment:)

Comment: @West1 I have added a photo to describe what I would like to have removed. Unfortunately, I don't think the frame view modifier does the trick.

Comment: I think the spacing is included in the font. But anyway this question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431791/14351818