# How to make text fill the height of the container in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make an HStack, where the views inside it are responsive to the size of the HStack frame. I have gotten this part down, but the issue I have is that the the text in the HStack does not reach the same height as the image beside it. Both containers are the same height --  however the text view does not actually reach the full height of its container (as seen by the background).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
 HStack {
    Image(systemName: "globe")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .background(Color.red)
    Text("Globe")
        .font(.system(size: 100))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        .background(Color.blue)
    
}.frame(height: 100)
```

This is the output my current code gives. I am looking to make the text reach the full height of its blue background.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that space is necessary for certain characters, else they might end up getting clipped.
[Characters using umlaut take that space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEm1c.png)

[Lowercase characters like g,p etc use that bottom space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y25fq.png)

[Characters like back slash etc too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exMVk.png)

If it is a fixed text, there might be some way to find the current text height of the characters used and apply a negative padding like @Md. Ibrahim Hassan has suggested. But I believe that the default space provided be left as is.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SwiftUI solution that is quite [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434598/5807290).

However, it uses hardcoded values.

Here is an alternate solution using some UIKit.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Color.red)
                        
            GeometryReader { geometryReader in
                MinimumVerticalPaddingSwiftUIView(size: geometryReader.size, text: "Globe")
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }.frame(height: 100)
    }
}

struct MinimumVerticalPaddingSwiftUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MinimumVerticalPaddingLabel
    
    var size: CGSize
    var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MinimumVerticalPaddingLabel {
        MinimumVerticalPaddingLabel(text: text, frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MinimumVerticalPaddingLabel, context: Context) {
        // You can update the UIView here if needed.
        // For this example, there's no need to update the UILabel.
    }
}

class MinimumVerticalPaddingLabel: UIView {
    var text: String = ""
    
    init(text: String, frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.text = text
        addBackgroundImagetoLayer()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    private func addBackgroundImagetoLayer() {
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size).image { rendererContext in
            let rect = frame
            UIColor.clear.setFill()
            rendererContext.fill(bounds)
            
            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: getAppropriateFontSize()) // Change the font size as needed
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font]

            let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            let textX = rect.origin.x + (rect.width - textSize.width) / 2
            let textY = rect.origin.y + (rect.height - textSize.height) / 2

            text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: textX, y: textY), withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        
        layer.contents = image.cgImage
    }
    
    func getAppropriateFontSize() -> CGFloat {
        var fontSize: CGFloat = 1
        
        var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font]
        var textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        
        while textSize.width <= frame.size.width {
            fontSize += 0.25
            font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
            attributes = [.font: font]
            textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        
        return fontSize
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The solution does not remove vertical padding but reduces it significantly.

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Original**

[image: Original]

Answer (score 0):

The post [Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63843516) has a useful explanation of the way a font is sized. So assuming you want the text to occupy the capHeight, you can use the information in `UIFont` to work out the excess height and padding that needs to be applied.

This gets you quite close (spot the tweak):

```swift
    private func fontForHeight(targetHeight: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        let approxFontSize = targetHeight * 1.4
        let refFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: approxFontSize)
        let computedFontSize = (targetHeight / refFont.capHeight) * approxFontSize
        let tweakedFontSize = computedFontSize - (targetHeight * 0.05)
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: tweakedFontSize)
    }

    private func content(targetHeight: CGFloat) -> some View {
        let uiFont = fontForHeight(targetHeight: targetHeight)
        let excessHeight = targetHeight - uiFont.capHeight
        return HStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Color.red)
            Text("Globe")
                .font(Font(uiFont))
                .frame(height: targetHeight + excessHeight)
                .background(
                    Color.blue
                        .padding(.vertical, excessHeight / 2)
                )
        }
        .frame(height: targetHeight)
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(targetHeight: 100)
    }
```

[image: TweakedGlobe]