How do I top-align Image and Text in SwiftUI without relying on magic numbers?
In SwiftUI, how do I top-align an Image and a Text, without relying on magic numbers?
This code:
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Text("50")
        .font(.largeTitle)

    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.right.circle.fill")
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundStyle(.gray.opacity(0.7))
}

results in this, where the image is not properly aligned:

I could probably solve this by using magic numbers to set a padding on the Image, but I want to avoid that.

I don't think it's possible. Texts are just designed to have a bit of vertical padding. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431791/5133585

The physical "top" of the text depends on a lot of factors, including what the text is. If you write 50Å for example, the image will be aligned with the physical top of the text. Would you want your image to suddenly move upwards when the text changes to 50Å, for example? Would you like it to suddenly move downwards when the text becomes lowercase "x"? This is a compromise that SwiftUI has taken, so that the height of the text doesn't change when the textual content changes.

@Sweeper Yes, would like it to do exactly that. I want it to align to what the content is now, not to what it could be

Is the text static? It will look very bizarre if the text can change - the image will be jumping up and down. If it is static then you might as well use magic numbers. This requirement is very unusual as far as typography goes.

By adding a .border to the text, we can see that the Text has some vertical padding, and that the image is indeed aligned to the top of that border.

The top padding is used to accommodate characters that are taller than usual. e.g. Å

In this case, the image will be aligned with the ring diacritic.
The bottom padding will be used to accommodate glyphs that e.g. have a descender, like y

The point is, the physical height of the text depends on the glyphs in the text, and it is will be jarring if the image always aligned to the physical top of the text. Consider
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Text("Å")
    Image("image1")
    Text("A")
    Image("image2")
    Text("x")
    Image("image3")
}

What do you expect the vertical positions of the three images to be? If their tops are all aligned with the physical tops of the text, the texts' baselines will not be aligned. If the baselines are aligned, then the images cannot all align with the physical tops of the texts, because they all have different heights.
You are fighting the system. At the end of the day, using magic numbers is inevitable, fonts can display each character with whatever physical height they want. You'd have to go into the font file and look at the vectors to calculate the physical height of a glyph.

In this specific case of "50" (where all characters are at cap-height) and the font is the system font, it seems like the top padding is the same as the bottom padding. You can technically do this without magic numbers.
Calculate the bottom padding by subtracting the baseline y from the bottom y, and shift the .top alignment guide of the text by that much.
Text("50A")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .border(.red)
    .alignmentGuide(.top) {
        $0[.top] + $0[.bottom] - $0[.lastTextBaseline]
    }



UIFont lets you read the dimensions of a font and you can use this information to calculate the top padding that is needed. The answer to the question Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text gives a good overview of these dimensions.
In this case, the problem is not quite so trivial, because the image does not extend all the way to the border of its frame. Here's what you see when you put a yellow background behind it:

So instead of using .largeTitle (to match the text), I would suggest using a slightly smaller font as the basis for determining the offset.
.title1 works well:
private var topOffset: CGFloat {
    let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
    return font.ascender - font.capHeight
}

If you wanted to align with the top of a lower-case letter then subtract font.xHeight, instead of font.capHeight.
You are already using .top alignment for the HStack, so the offset can be applied as top padding to the image:
Image(systemName: "arrow.up.right.circle.fill")
    .font(.caption)
    .foregroundStyle(.gray.opacity(0.7))
    .padding(.top, topOffset) //  Apply the top offset as padding


